# Gatsby unable to render background-image when image path determined by props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm working on a Gatsby project and I've run into a frustrating problem. I have a component that receives a relative path to an image as props, which I then use to populate a `background-image` property:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

// Prop typings
type TProps = {
  imageUrl: string;
}

const MyComponent: FC<TProps> = ({ imageUrl }) => {

  const divStyles = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
  }

  return (
    <div style={divStyles}></div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

The relative path passed in `imageUrl` references an image in my `src` directory. I've double-checked that the path is correct and the image exists, yet the image won't appear when the component renders.

I can set the background image successfully using CSS, but it fails when the image path is passed as a prop. I've also tried setting the image URL using Gatsby's `withPrefix` utility function, but no dice.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just impossible to define a background image in Gatsby from props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show an image like this it's not a `Gatsby` issue, but a `React` related question.

This is the right way to import an image in `React` and pass it down with `props`:

```
// Parent component
import image from "../relative/path/to/image";

<MyGreatComponent image={image} />

// MyGreatComponent

export default function MyGreatComponent({ image }) {
const divStyles = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${image}`,
  }

  return (
    <div style={divStyles}></div>
  )
}
```

Reference: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong, or is it just impossible to define a
> background image in Gatsby from props?

You should be able to, as any other React project.

The only problem I think you may be facing is the relativity of the paths. Without knowing the current offending path (`imageUrl`) or how's your project structure it's difficult to guess but try something like:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

// Prop typings
type TProps = {
  imageUrl: string;
}

const MyComponent: FC<TProps> = ({ imageUrl }) => {

  const divStyles = {
    backgroundImage: `url(../${imageUrl})`,
  }

  return (
    <div style={divStyles}></div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```